# Microsoft Integration Runtime losing Authentication Key on Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-data-factory

I currently have an Azure Virtual Machine that is running Windows Server 2019 Datacenter that I use as a connection point for Azure Data Factory. The Integration Runtime works and so do the pipelines that utilize it.

The issue arises when the Virtual Machine is shut down at night and started back up in the morning using Runbooks. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAMvY.png). "The Authentication Key is invalid or empty. Specify a valid Authentication Key from the portal"

This does not always happen. The Integration Runtime can work for a few days and then it stops with the error above. It seems like the only solution is to re-install the Integration Runtime and re-do the linked services in Azure Data Factory.

I have spent some time trying to figure out what could be causing this error and it seems a little weird that it can work for several days before the error comes up. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when the server clock (windows VM in this case with self-hosted IR running) time is not in sync with the remote server (the ADF service).

As a prerequisite, you should sync the clock on the Windows VM with the internet or update this yourself before you register the IR again.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the suggestion. My VM is currently on UTC and within the server manager, the time zone is set as UTC as well. Would this satisfy the requirements you have mentioned?

My ADF is in Canad Central. Would I have to change the VM and server manager to reflect the time-zone that my ADF is in?

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick for you. Synchronized clocks mainly to ensure the messages are fresh and to prevent replay attacks.

Comment: Hey @Raunak, at first it worked for a few days, and then the same error occurred requiring me to re-install the Integration Runtime. Do you by any chance have any other suggestions of what could be causing it?

Comment: What about the time zone? Are they in sync? Also good to engage Microsoft support as this may require log analysis & backend telemetry analysis.